# FHIR's General-Purpose Data Type Object Parsing From JSON in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, types, hl7-fhir, jsonparser, fhir-net-api

I am using [Hl7.Fhir.R4](https://github.com/FirelyTeam/fhir-net-api/tree/develop-r4) library in my project which is an API Wrapper (in ASP.NET Core 2.2) around [Azure API for FHIR](https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server).
In a View Model, I declared a FHIR Element ([FHIR's General-Purpose Data Type](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/datatypes.html)) as a property. Example:

```
public class MyPatient
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public Hl7.Fhir.Model.CodeableConcept MaritalStatus { get; set;} //This is 
                                                          //defined in the library
}
```

Now, the **problem** is: The 'MaritalStatus' is not being parsed from json to the c# object ([defined in the library](https://github.com/FirelyTeam/fhir-net-api/blob/develop-r4/src/Hl7.Fhir.Core/Model/Generated/CodeableConcept.cs)), properly (i.e it is just 'not null'). Neither is there any exception being thrown.

**Explained With Details:**
This is the JSON I am receiving from the front-end:

```
 { 
   "name": "TheName", 
   "maritalStatus": {
      "coding": [ 
         { 
           "system": "terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-MaritalStatus", 
           "code": "U", 
           "display": "unmarried"
         } 
       ], 
      "text": "Unmarried" 
    } 
}
```

This is my model (C# class) against the JSON I am receiving from the front-end:

```
public class MyPatient
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public Hl7.Fhir.Model.CodeableConcept MaritalStatus { get; set;}
}
```

This the controller's action (in the wrapper layer - my project) which is entertaining the request:

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Update([Required][FromRoute] string id,[Required][FromBody] MyPatient myPatient)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

               Hl7.Fhir.Model.Patient patient = await _fhirClient.ReadAsync<Patient>(location: "Patient/" + id);

               patient.MaritalStatus = myPatient.MaritalStatus;

               patient.Name[0].Text = myPatient.Name;

               patient = await _fhirClient.UpdateAsync<Patient>(patient);

               return Ok();

            }//ends If ModelState.IsValid

            return BadRequest();
        }//ends Update
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are doing?
How are you parsing, what does the json look like? Why are you not parsing to a regular FHIR Patient object when you say you are using the official library? Why do you need a 'MyPatient' class?

Comment: 1. I need to update Patient FHIR resource in Azure FHIR Db. I take the 'maritalStatus' object, in JSON, from the front-end, Json.NET (the default JSON Parser in .NET Core) parses that object into the C# object (Type: CodeableConcept). Then I store the reference of this C# object in the retrieved FHIR resource Patient.MaritalStatus. And finally, I make update call to the Azure FHIR Server taking this locally updated object.
2. I am parsing using the default JSON Converter in .NET Core.
3. I need to allow the user to only update the patient object partially (i.e 'MaritalStatus).

Comment: The json looks like:
{
    "name": "TheName",
    "maritalStatus": {
        "coding": [
            {
                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-MaritalStatus",
                "code": "U",
                "display": "unmarried"
            }
        ],
        "text": "Unmarried"
    }
}

Comment: I only need to parse the 'maritalStatus' of type 'CodeableConcept', which I am taking from the front-end in the wrapper layer. So, Its impossible to parse it into whole Patient FHIR object.
@MirjamBaltus

Answer (score 1):

First, your instance isn't valid FHIR.  You need to adhere to the syntax defined in the FHIR spec - and 'name' on Patient is not a simple string.  As well, you need to declare the resourceType.  That's not optional.  Second, if you want to use the official library, you can't go off and invent your own classes and expect them to magically work - use the built-in parser.  It'll be perfectly fine even if you've only got two elements present (plus the resourceType).

Comment: I request you to please read the question and comments again. I am sorry but I don't think that your answer is relevant at all. This whole question is actually about mapping between View Model and FHIR Domain Model in a wrapper layer around Azure FHIR Server.

Comment: My comment was about your JSON - it's not valid FHIR.  (Try posting it to any of the public FHIR test servers if you want to verify.)  So it's unsurprising that the parser has an issue.  Also, your code snippit doesn't seem to be performing any mapping.  It's simply defining a new class.

Comment: I have explained the question to enough descriptive level. I hope now you would understand that your answer was not relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mention using the default JSON Converter of .Net Core, so I'm assuming that is the one in System.Text.Json.

The problem is not with the FHIR library, since that is perfectly capable of parsing FHIR json correctly into FHIR objects. So you'll have to look at the JSON converter you use for your custom class, and get it to parse the json correctly into your class object. Looking at that, I think the problem is a case mismatch. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?view=netcore-3.1#deserialization-behavior) indicates that property name matching is case-sensitive. FHIR properties use camel case, but the properties of the FHIR model start with uppercase. To get around this, set your serialization properties, and use them for the deserialization:

```
        var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };

        var myPatient = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyPatient>(json, serializerOptions);
```